# python3 syntax: * before variable

Tags: python-3.x

```
g = dominoes.Game.new()

for _ in range(fixed_moves):
    g.make_move(*g.valid_moves[0])
```

In the last line, what does the `*` before object `g` mean?

Comment: Please do your research first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asterisks (`*`) in arguments are used for unpacking.

For example:

```
def f(n, m):
  pass

l = [2, 3]
f(*l)
```

This will unpack `l` and will make the parameters `n` and `m` `2` and `3`, respectively.